# Can there be more than one natural transformation between two functors?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $\eta : S \dot{\rightarrow} T$ is a natural transformation.

**Question:** Is it possible that there could be another natural transformation $\eta' : S \dot{\rightarrow} T$ s.t. $\eta \ne \eta'$?

Comment: In general there are tons. Look up the Yoneda lemma for a large class of examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in general it is possible. For example, consider two constant functors, so that $S$ sends every object to an object $s$ and $T$ send every object to an object $t$, and both of them send every morphism to the identity; then any map $s\to t$ is a natural transformation $S\dot{\to}T$.

For another example, there are (at least) two transformations from the identity functor on the category of vector spaces to itself : the zero transformation and the identity.

Comment: Any scalar $\lambda \in k$ defines a transformation $\mathrm{id}_{Vect_k} \to \mathrm{id}_{Vect_k}$.

Comment: @HeinrichD Good point. I initially wanted to state my example in an arbitrary pointed category, which is why I only mentioned those two natural transformations.

Comment: So if the functor is injectively maps objects, there is only one natural transformation, right?

Comment: @roundsquare The second example is injective on objects.